# Headset for both plane and heli: buy for plane, use adapter for heli, or vice versa?

Tags: headset

I fly both planes and helicopters and am about to buy a Bose A20. I'm wondering if I should get the helicopter version with a U-174 plug and a coiled cable, or the plane version with a dual plug and a straight cable. (In both cases of course I'd also get an adapter to go from one plug to the other.) Does someone have recommendations as to which way to go? E.g. is the coiled cable a hassle in the plane, or a feature? Is one of the two plug types better, or more impaired by the adapter? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There's no issues with the adapter either way, as long as it's good quality. The helicopter versions are coiled for a good reason: to keep it out of your way, so I would buy the helicopter version. In most fixed wing airplanes the coil will be absolutely fine, if there's not enough reach you can get extenders pretty easily.